# How does damage work in Far Cry Primal?

Tags: far-cry-primal

I've been playing Far Cry Primal for a while now and I don't understand how the damage system works. I find it confusing that you have a set of hit points, but you don't lose them in discrete amounts - lots of things do fraction of a hit point worthy of damage to the player.

But what's really confusing to me are the damage stats of weapons. My bow says it deals 3 points of damage, while my spear does 2. Yet I can kill human enemies with either two arrows or one spear (not considering headshots).

On top of that, information sources such as the fandom wiki are no help. The [entry for the elder mammoth](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/Mammoth) says it's got five points of life and does five damage. I have evidence in contrary, because when they hit me I lose only two hit points. But worse still, there is this wooly beast which I've named Prickney Spears after I personally turned him into a pin cushion and he refused to die. I counted and there were five spears in it, so should've been at least 10 damage.

What am I not understanding about the way you count numbers in this game? Because this all seems like [caveman math](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2012-12-21) to me.